# Midi Hexa-Code Notation Different in one fie

Tags: midi

I have those 3 Events in a Midi file:

```
00 FF 51 03 0E 15 C3 86 A6

20 FF 51 03 15 20 A5 83

5C FF 51 03 0E 15 C3
```

But what is, in this case, important is, that `FF 51` stands for a Tempo Change and the `03` for the number of following Byte-Pairs describing the tempo. As it is "3 Byte Pairs" in Each Event Why are there 5 Byte Pairs describing the first Event, 4 describing the second, and 3 describing the third? (I hope the image helps)

How does the encoding program know, when a new Event starts? The File can be played without any Problems.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three events have three data bytes.

The delta times between the events are encoded as variable-length quantities, so you have to continue to read bytes until the most significant bit is clear. The three times before each event are `00`, `86 A6 20`, and `83 5C`, resulting in the decoded delta times of 0, 109344, and 476.

Comment: Oh that is what i missunderstood.  Thank you my friend and i wish you nice holidays!